# Which element makes the site not responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

When you open this website http://beaton.wizedesign.com/ 
with a mobile phone (or with a desktop browser with minimized window), you can notice that the website is not responsive, I couldn't find why, even if I disable the audio player and I reduce the width of the backstretch div the problem still remains, can you please help me to find which element causes the site to be non responsive ?

Comment: `#fap-main` is causing that horizontal scrollbar

Comment: No, it's width is 100%.

Answer (score 0):

when i check it with the chrome developer tools it is responsive so it might be a problem with not having the right css for every browser